# Why my net2ftp file manager isn't working?

Tags: file-manager

my net2ftp file manager says

```
An error has occured
Unable to connect to FTP server ......... on port 21.
Are you sure this is the address of the FTP server? This is often different from that of the HTTP (web) server. Please contact your ISP helpdesk or system administrator for help.
```

and here are the technical details:

```
The error occured in file /home/files/public_html/3/includes/filesystem.inc.php on line 56.
function ftp_openconnection (/home/files/public_html/3/modules/browse/browse.inc.php on line 234)
function net2ftp_module_printBody (/home/files/public_html/3/main.inc.php on line 320)
function net2ftp (/home/files/public_html/3/index.php on line 61)
argument 0: printBody
```

could anybody help me with figuring out what it is or is it just my browser
I tried using different settings but it didn't help
P.S I'm not connecting using my own manager im using my hosting (which is hostinger.co.uk) provider's file manager and I can login into it sometimes but not for a long time

Comment: Could you include your code with what you try to connect to FTP server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it all by myself. I searched for net2ftp, downloaded and installed it into my site myself.

Answer (score 0):

Your FTP server is running... see:

```
C:\>telnet hashbang.co.cc 21

421 50 users (the maximum) are already logged in, sorry

Host connection lost.

C:\>
```

So, it's working but, as message says, there are 50 open connection (at the time I've clicked)

Good luck.